# How to prove the separable functions continuous?

Tags: calculus

Assume $f(x,y)$ is continuous, and $f(x,y)$ can be expressed as the sums of separable functions. That's to say $$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{r}g_{i}(x)h_{i}(y)$$
where $g_{i}(x),g_{j}(x)(i\not =j)$ are independent, and So are the $h_{i}(y),h_{j}(y)$.

My question is: Are $g_{i}(x),h_{i}(y)$ continuous? $i=1,2...r$

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Take $h_i(y) = 1$ for all $y$ and $i=1,2$. Let

$$g_1(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x\in\Bbb Q\\ 0, & x\not\in\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

and likewise let

$$g_2(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x\in\Bbb Q\\ 1, & x\not\in\Bbb Q\end{cases}.$$

Note that $g_1(x)+g_2(x) = 1$ for any $x$. Then

$$f(x,y) = g_1(x)h_1(y)+g_2(x)h_2(y) = g_1(x)\cdot 1+g_2(x)\cdot 1 = 1$$

so $f$ is continuous but the $g_i$ are not necessarily continuous, even though the $h_i$ are continuous. I think the best you can do is to say that $\sum_i g_i$ is continuous and likewise for $h_i$. You can't say anything specific about the individual components.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a condition $g_{i}(x),g_{j}(x)$, $h_{i}(y),h_{j}(y)$ should be independent. $i \not \not= j$